# How to remove the gap between columns in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to remove the gap between the columns in bootstrap.[image: See the image]

Comment: here is my code: https://codepen.io/sadiquekp/details/abOMjQe

Answer (score 0):

Use this library which do this beautifully.
https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).